# Cannot open .profile in OSX terminal

Tags: macos

Just bought a brand new Mac and trying to set some stuff up for school. I need to run the "open .profile" command from the Terminal, however I receive the following message:

```
The file /Users/user/.profile does not exist
```

I read online another option that if this occurs, I should run the command "vi.profile" to create the file. However, that returns the following error message:

```
-bash: vi.profile: command not found
```

I am completely new to Mac/Linux, if anyone has any help/suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a .profile in /Users/user, first `touch /Users/user/.profile` (to create the file), and then you can `vi /Users/user/.profile` to edit it.  You might want to open the file with whatever osx's default text editor is - vim has a pretty steep learning curve.  The reason your `vi.profile` command isn't working, btw, is because you are missing a space between `vi`, which is the program you are calling, and `.profile`, which is the argument  you are passing to that program.